# Display facet names on ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I can't figure out why the following code do not display any name for the facets of my plots. If anyone as a hint that would be welcome.

```
data <- data.frame(id = rep(c("Large choice", "Low prices", "Service quality", "Product quality", "Convenience"), 4), 
                   variable = rep(factor(c("OfficeStar", "Paper and Co", "Office Equipment", "Supermarket"), 
                   levels = c("OfficeStar", "Paper and Co", "Office Equipment", "Supermarket")), each = 5), 
                   value = sample(30, 20), 
                   focus = as.factor(c(rep(1,5), rep(0, 15)))); 
nb_col <- 3

> head(data, 10)
       id             variable       value   focus
       Large choice   OfficeStar     5.2     1
         Low prices   OfficeStar     2.1     1
    Service quality   OfficeStar     4.2     1
    Product quality   OfficeStar     3.7     1
        Convenience   OfficeStar     2.7     1
       Large choice   Paper and Co   4.4     0
         Low prices   Paper and Co   4.5     0
    Service quality   Paper and Co   2.3     0
    Product quality   Paper and Co   2.6     0
        Convenience   Paper and Co   1.4     0
```

When I run the code:

```
ggplot(data = data, aes(x = variable, y = value, fill = focus)) +
     geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
     facet_wrap(~id, ncol = nb_col, drop = FALSE) +
     scale_fill_manual(values = c("#77bb77", "#5599bb")) +
     coord_flip() +
     theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),
           axis.title.y = element_blank(),
           panel.grid   = element_blank(),
           legend.position = "none")
```

I get:

[image]

The first facet should be named Large choice here for instance.
I must also mention that the data table is obtained via a user input so I do not know before hand what id will look like though I know they will be strings.

I have tried to apply levels to id because there was noone, however it did not work and I tried to use the labeller function, but nothing either.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] gridExtra_2.2.1 ggrepel_0.5     GMD_0.3.3       cluster_2.0.4   proto_0.3-10    lme4_1.1-12     Matrix_1.2-6    MASS_7.3-45     nnet_7.3-12    
[10] sendmailR_1.2-1 RODBC_1.3-13    scales_0.4.0    ggplot2_2.1.0   gplots_3.0.1    stringr_1.1.0   digest_0.6.10   reshape2_1.4.1 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.6        magrittr_1.5       splines_3.3.1      munsell_0.4.3      lattice_0.20-33    colorspace_1.2-6   minqa_1.2.4        plyr_1.8.4        
 [9] caTools_1.17.1     tools_3.3.1        nlme_3.1-128       gtable_0.2.0       KernSmooth_2.23-15 gtools_3.5.0       nloptr_1.0.4       base64enc_0.1-3   
[17] bitops_1.0-6       labeling_0.3       gdata_2.17.0       stringi_1.1.1
```

Comment: What do you wonder about focus ?

Comment: Oh, sorry I failed to make data. modified ver; `data <- data.frame(id = rep(c("Large choice", "Low prices", "Service quality", "Product quality", "Convenience"), 4), variable = rep(factor(c("OfficeStar", "Paper and Co", "Office Equipment", "Supermarket"), levels = c("OfficeStar", "Paper and Co", "Office Equipment", "Supermarket")), each = 5), value = sample(30, 20), focus = as.factor(c(rep(1,5), rep(0, 15)))); nb_col <- 3` But I can't reproduce it when I run your `ggplot` code.

Comment: Voting to close as not reproducible.

Comment: What version of ggplot2 are you using? Posting the output of `sessionInfo()` plus including the code that @cuttlefish44 was kind enough to create for you would probably help keep this question open and it'll be more reproducible if it really is a problem. One last thing: did you try this in a **fresh** R session?

Comment: Your example isn't reproducible. We can't run the code based on what you've provided. At a guess, there's some other variable or setting lurking in your R environment that is causing your issue.

Comment: This is somewhat a good news, meaning that I don't have to investigate that aspect. Thank you and I will keep you updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found where the problem was. Obviously with a partial code you could not find it...

We had a piece of code somewhere in another file which was called before stating:

```
theme_update(strip.text.x = element_blank())
```

Since the default is `switch = "x"` in `facet_wrap`, it could not work. When I do the following however, it works fine:

```
ggplot(data = data, aes(x = variable, y = value, fill = focus)) +
       geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
       facet_wrap(~id, ncol = 3, drop = FALSE, labeller = "label_value", switch = "y") +
       coord_flip() +
       theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),
             axis.title.y = element_blank(),
             panel.grid   = element_blank(),
             legend.position = "none")
```